# Why is the power factor always 0.8?

Tags: power

If reactive power means losses, why don't we correct the power factor and make it 1? For example, on marine vessels that I have been working on, the power factor is always 0.8. We could add capacitors in parallel, or over-excite a generator.

Why this is never the case?

Comment: "If reactive power means losses" there is your problem. Reactive power only means losses, mostly financial, to the power company. It has no effect on your application.

Comment: [Power Factor Correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor#Power_factor_correction_.28PFC.29_in_non-linear_loads) is a thing and it is practiced where it is judged to be beneficial.

Comment: @Trevor Why no effects? When power factor increases I see that the current is lower

Comment: @Trevor Current is lower when power factor is higher. This is the reason we correct power factor. But why we do not totally correct?

Comment: @sofky, there is a cost associated with PF correction and no real benefit to the customer unless the electric company charges you a premium for having a low PF.

Comment: Whether you over-excite your generator or run it lagging, the power still comes from the generator.  You could add capacitors, but the load is dynamic.  If the load is not inductive, capacitors may consume more power.  You could add capacitors on an individual load basis.  That costs.

Comment: PF is the ratio of real power (W) to apparent power (VA) where VA is the sum of real power and reactive power (VAR).   +ve Reactive power can be reduced with -ve reactive power with large capacitors only if the current is a pure sine wave.  Capacitor balancing is expensive and Harmonic balancing is even more complex and expensive and is done in bulk when it is only feasible compared to cost upgrades of generator when there is insufficient power to meet demand that can be achieved by this method.  Often it is not feasible as pulse loads from pumps and battery chargers are usually not linear.

Comment: This pulse load means energy is stored then released in pulses so this "stored energy" is effectively VAR or VA reactive stored energy that reduces PF and cannot be offset by simple cap solution.

Comment: When you say the PF is 0.8, that's *under what conditions*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Power factor is not corrected to 1 because power the power factor is likely to change with changing load. With correction to 1, the power factor could become leading and that is often more difficult for the source to accommodate. It could cause the voltage to rise.

In your marine vessel example, the engine generator set may be designed for 0.8 pf. If the engine is sized to produce a certain KW and the generator is designed to produce a KVA that is 20% more than that, there is not much to be gained by adjusting to anything higher than 0.8.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why is a leading power factor more difficult to accomodate?

Comment: I don't know exactly why leading power factor is problematic. The problem may be localized voltage increase that could be corrected by a system that automatically adds capacitive correction and subtracts it when it is not needed. However utilities typically charge industrial customers a penalty for power factor lower than something like 0.85 or 0.9. For other customers, there is typically no charge. Losses on the customer side of the meter are usually small enough to make it not worthwhile to use sophisticated correction schemes.

Answer (score 3):

Power factors are often "corrected." Typically, line loads from electric companies are inductive loads (transformers, high power industrial motors, etc). So the solution is to have some giant capacitor, which is not terribly uncommon.

Why don't we correct everything? It's not ever possible, and usually it's not practical. Inductance is not constant. E.g. night time, there is less power going to industrial machines so the inductive load may go down. If you correct the P.F. for these inductive loads, your P.F. will change again when those loads are turned off.

Comment: One cannot overemphasize this. It's the loads which set the power factor in the network, not the generator. A synchronous generator can deliver both inductive and capacitive reactive power, and switch between these two states rather quickly. So the reason why the power factor was "fixed" at 0.8ind was the mostly inductive load in the vessel's electrical network. Most likely coming from hundreds and hundreds of asynchronous machines driving hydraulic pumps.

Answer (score 3):

You list two alternatives:

- over excite generator.
- power factor correction.

We could over-excite the generator and supply leading reactive power to cancel out lagging reactive power and make power factor 1.  But you have done nothing, since the genset still supplies the same apparent power.  No gain.

Power factor correction is viable, but is costly.  It can be done for total or on a load by load basis.  To date, ship owners have been reluctant to make this investment, because if you compare cost of running ships' auxiliaries to cost of propulsion, the extra cost of running with lagging power factors is negligible.

I say *to date* because with EEDI (Energy Efficient Design Index), designers of new ships have to achieve 10% (20% and eventually 30%) reduction in \$CO_2\$ emissions.  A portion of this (5% to 8% at 30%) would have to come from the electrical system, so things like power factor correction are viable.  But even there, there are better options.  So it is an option, but I do not see it being used in many vessels.

On land, over-exciting synchronous motors and power factor correction are done to reduce power factors to reduce a facilities power factor, so power companies do not charge a surcharge for each kWh consumed.

At sea, there is no benefit to improve the power factor since the vessel is the producer and consumer of power.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, power factor *is* corrected in many cases to reduce line currents and the associated distribution losses. Large industrial main loads are required or incentivized by the utility company to reach a minimum power factor by installing capacitors or active PFC.

Active PFC is starting to show up in consumer electrics, as well, to improve the situation from the buttom. Some "green" certifications, such as certain Energy Star certifications, specificy a minimum PF. You can find off the shelf LED bulbs that feature active PFC in order to reduce the harmonic currents that are generally introduced by rectifiers.

For more information, see the following links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor#Importance_of_power_factor_in_distribution_systems

http://www.eaton.com/ecm/groups/public/@pub/@electrical/documents/content/sa02607001e.pdf

http://powerelectronics.com/power-management/power-factor-correction-justified-home

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of an over excited generator!
Generator excitation controls the output voltage and is set to give the required output voltage.

Most large ships have an over excited synchronous motor driving a forced draft fan, which every large engine room will have. These are switched on during commissioning of the vessel and remain on throughout the life of the vessel.

Being synchronous they are used for power factor correction and have been in use for decades.

Comment: Some good information here, but it does not specifically answer the question.  Why is the power factor adjusted to always be 0.8 instead of 1?